# Groupcount strings by number

Tags: r, group-by

How can I *group-count* strings by numbers? I have the following data:

```
test.df = read.csv(file = "test.csv", header = TRUE)
```

Content

```
iso_a2,FID_Consum
DE,1
DE,1
PT,1
PT,1
DE,1
EN,2
EN,2
PT,3
EN,4
GR,5
```

I would like to add another column which counts how often the iso_a2 value shows up in all rows if FID_equals the number in the row e.g.

```
iso_a2,FID_Consum,count
DE,1,3
DE,1,3
PT,1,2
PT,1,2
DE,1,3
EN,2,2
EN,2,2
PT,3,1
EN,4,1
GR,5,1
```

Comment: Returns `Error in df$iso_a2 : object of type 'closure' is not subsettable`

Comment: I did use test.df

Comment: Please make your example [reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example), show `dput(test.df)`; edit your question!